# Android In Code get the Version of App?

Tags: version, xamarin.android

I'm looking for the way to get the version of the app so I can display it in the About screen in my Android app.

In iOS (MonoTouch.net) we'd just do this:

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary ("CFBundleVersion").ToString ();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [PackageManager.GetPackageInfo](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo%20%28string,%20Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags%29) method to get access to all sorts of information about your app, including [VersionCode](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Content.PM.PackageInfo.VersionCode) and [VersionName](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Content.PM.PackageInfo.VersionName)

Comment: `GetPackageInfo` requires two parameters: the package name and flags. Just use the following code to get the package info for your application: `this.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(this.PackageName, 0)`

Comment: Thanks @Erik! If you need this in a place without an activity context you can do `Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName` etc.