# Retrieve the version code of the App in Android

Tags: java, android, version-control

How can I retrieve the version code of my application programmatically?

I checked [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086218/android-in-code-get-the-version-of-app) question but all the links are broken

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this, [CURRENT_ACTIVITY].class);
    PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(comp.getPackageName(), 0);

    int versionCode = pinfo.versionCode;

} catch(android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
```

Replace "[CURRENT_ACTIVITY]" with the actual name of your activity. (Just to clarify haha)

Answer (score 1):

[`context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)`.`[`getPackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager%28%29)`().`[`getPackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)`(context.`[`getPackageName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29)`()).`[`versionCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode)