# Get the version number from an app from within a library

Tags: android

I am working on android library that can be referenced in a developers project. What I need to be able to do, is from the library, get the version number from the main app.

For example, I have an application called `My Application Test`, this application references the library `MyLibrary`.

The developer calls a function to `MyLibrary` from `My Application Test` and `MyLibrary` has to get the version of `My Application Test` not `MyLibrary`.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086218/android-in-code-get-the-version-of-app

Comment: Yea that question worked.