# Get Android library module version number from inside demo app

Tags: android, version-control, android-library

I can programmatically get my app's version name like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119027/3681880):

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME; // 1.0
```

However, I have a demo app for a [library](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library) I am making. In my project (since the library and the demo app are in the same project) I use

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":mongol-library")
}
```

In other apps people would import it with

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.studymongolian:mongol-library:0.9.16'
}
```

In the demo app I would like to include the library's version name rather than the demo app version name. I could hard code the string, of course and update it every time that I updated the library, but that would be error prone. Is there a way to programmatically access a library module's version name?

Related questions

- [Get the version number from an app from within a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136643/get-the-version-number-from-an-app-from-within-a-library)
- [Android.Gradle: Is it possible to get current module name programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502191/android-gradle-is-it-possible-to-get-current-module-name-programmatically)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use
`String libVersionName = your.lib.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;`

or in your library, just use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` to get it.

---

NB:
`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in app module is `your.app.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`

Comment: This worked very well. In my particular demo app I got the library version name with this: `String versionName = net.studymongolian.mongollibrary.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;`

Comment: This will not work if you are using an app module inside your project to test your library module. It will end up returning the versionName from the build.gradle that is associated with your app module and not your library module, even if you specify the package of your library.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the other options with BuildConfig didn't work out for me.
I ended up with this code:

```java
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package.name", 0).versionName
```

For my library "com.package.name" was only the first part of the dependency from build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.package.name:library:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Not worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67785357/538408

Comment: This is the version of the app's package name, not the dependency, no?